# Laravel Auth::attempt alway return false

Tags: laravel

I don't know why Auth:attempt alway return false.
Here is my controller:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    $user = [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
    ];

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($user)) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
  use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'admin'], function () {
Route::get('login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
Route::get('logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard.index');
    })->name('admin.dashboard');

    });
});
```

In controller i get array from html to send. But when in  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($user)) is alway false. I don't know why.
Please help me.
Thank so much.

Comment: Try removing the bcrypt on `bcrypt($request['password'])` before the attempt, leaving just `'password' => $request['password'],`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ it's still return false. I don't know why.